# how can I do domain forward on google cloud engine?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I have a *laravel* project that deployed on google cloud computing (VM instance), and another project that deployed on google app engine *react project*.
let the first project have this domain **firstproject.com**
how can I make the second project domain related to the first one, like **firstproject.com/secound**

Comment: What you've investigated or tried so far?

Comment: to be honest, I read a lot about this topic, but I can't reach what I need.
I read about load balance, subdomain forward .. etc but that not what I want.
if you have any idea that could help me, I will be happy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some options are

1. Try your domain name registrar. some of them offer domain name forwarding
2. Instead of doing a domain name forwarding, you can also write code to internally make the call to your Google App Engine (GAE) project and display the result to your user. e.g.

   say your GAE project is - `myproject.appspot.com`

   your code will receive a request `firstproject.com/second/page1` and internally make a call to `myproject.appspot.com/page1`, retrieve the data and return it to the user. This means the user is always seeing `firstproject.com/second/page1`
3. Instead of having second as directory firstproject.com, you could make it a subdomain i.e. `second.firstproject.com` and map it directly on Google App Engine